# Awk throws "No such file or directory error" where using hostname -I

Tags: linux, bash, awk

This command works fine are print the hostname

```
awk -v MYHOST=$(hostname) '{printf(MYHOST)}'
```

However on running

```
awk -v MYHOST=$(hostname -I) '{printf(MYHOST)}'
```

throws a

```
awk: cannot open "ip address" (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Yeah . the host has multiple ip addresses . So works with the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You should [always use double-quotes around command substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). The following command is fixed, it will not throw the error:

```
awk -v MYHOST="$(hostname -I)" '{printf(MYHOST)}'
```

---

With `$(hostname -I)` unquoted, these are possible outcomes (after expansion):

- ```
  awk -v MYHOST= '{printf(MYHOST)}'
  ```

  This will formally work.
- ```
  awk -v MYHOST=1.2.3.4 '{printf(MYHOST)}'
  ```

  This will formally work.
- ```
  awk -v MYHOST=1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8 '{printf(MYHOST)}'
  ```

  This will treat `5.6.7.8` as a script and `{printf(MYHOST)}` as a file to be parsed. The error will be like `cannot open '{printf(MYHOST)}' (No such file or directory)`, unless there is such file.
- ```
  awk -v MYHOST=1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8 9.10.11.12 … '{printf(MYHOST)}'
  ```

  where `…` indicates zero or more additional addresses. This will treat `5.6.7.8` as a script and `9.10.11.12 … '{printf(MYHOST)}'` as multiple files to be parsed. The error will mention the first nonexistent "file", e.g. `cannot open '9.10.11.12' (No such file or directory)`.

  This is what happened in your case.